# How do I themeroll jGrowl

Tags: jquery-ui, themeroller, jgrowl

I am working on building a site and i'm trying to use jquery ui themes for as much of the styling as possible.  and the jGrowl site says it can be theme rolled.

from the site:

> Changes in 1.2.2
>        Notification can now be theme rolled for jQuery UI, special thanks to Jeff Chan!

there isn't really any explanation as to how and i searched far and wide for an explanation to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to do anything, simply include the jquery-ui css. There are example files included for different themes in the download