# Use JGrowl with Theme roller

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jgrowl

I want to know how to use my Jquery UI theme with JGrowl. The site says it can be done. The questions is answered here:

[How do I themeroll jGrowl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150397/how-do-i-themeroll-jgrowl)

and the asker seemed happy with the answer, however I did what the solution said: include the Jquery ui css file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.css" type="text/css"/>
```

But it does not use my custom theme. I tried not linking to the jgrowl.css file, but then it did not work right at all.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure all those files exist at the correct paths. Also, check your Javascript console for any runtime errors.

Comment: They do exist at those paths. Also the redmond theme and jquery and jquery ui work elsewhere on the page. In fact, the whole page is built using jquery. Also, the JGrowl works, but uses the original theme, not the redmond one... unless i'm missing where the redmond theme specifies that the notifications should be black... i would think they should be blue or yellow, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You express concern that it might actually be working, but with unexpected coloring. To test this, switch to a different jQuery theme, and see if the jGrowl elements change.

If they don't, check the jGrowl version. According to http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jgrowl-question, version 1.2.0 doesn't use jQuery-ui themes automatically, but version 1.2.4 does.

Comment: Ok. good idea I'll check that later today, would be odd coincidence that my theme has the same color as the default JGrowl theme. thanks.

Comment: ugh. i guess your right. If i don't link to the jquery ui redmond css file then the "close all" is black not yellow. However the color of the actual message stay the same... very odd...

Comment: If you don't like the way the Redmond theme looks with jGrowl, you might consider another theme. Here are some theme options from the Google CDN: http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/latest-jquery-and-jquery-ui-theme-links.html. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll take a look! I just don't understand where the black comes from. I looked on themeroller and could not figure out what property was set to black that JGrowl might be taking. Not too much documentation from JGrowl to figure it out. I'll have to dive into the code next week.